# WPF DataGrid Combobox column not saving values when item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've wanted to create a ComboBoxColumn with specific options for each row

e.g.

List string

```
        public ObservableCollection<string> FilterTypes { get; set; }
```

Lists itself

```
public static class FilterCharacters
    {
        public static Dictionary<FilterTypes, string> FilterCharactersList => new Dictionary<FilterTypes, string>()
                {
                    {FilterTypes.Equals, "=" },
                    {FilterTypes.NotEquals, "!=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Greater, ">" },
                    {FilterTypes.GreaterOrEqual, ">=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Less, "<" },
                    {FilterTypes.LessOrEqual, "<=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Contains, "contains" },
                    {FilterTypes.NotContains, "does not contain" },
                    {FilterTypes.True, "True" },
                    {FilterTypes.False, "False" }
                };

        public static List<string> NumberList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Greater],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.GreaterOrEqual],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Less],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.LessOrEqual],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Equals],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotEquals]
        };

        public static List<string> TextList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Contains],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotContains],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Equals],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotEquals]
        };

        public static List<string> BoolList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.True],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.False]
        };
    }
```

and xaml

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" Header="Check">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=FilterTypes}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=FilterTypes}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Using answer of my previous question i managed to display those items in the combo box but then i can not select other than the first one (which is empty). Whenever i select something and change cell the selection is gone with no errow thrown. I've tried using `SelectedItemBidning` but it resulted in an conversion error from string to ObservableCollection, when removed the selecteditembinding there is no error but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set or bound the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable<T>`, you should set the `SelectedItemBinding` property to a binding to a string property of the type `T` that holds the currently selected value:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" Header="Check"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedFilerType}">
...
```

---

```
public class Item
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> FilterTypes { get; set; }
    ...

    private string _selectedFilerType;
    public string SelectedFilerType
    {
        get { return _selectedFilerType; }
        set { _selectedFilerType = value; /*...*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried with a string property but i did not work for some reason, this has worked!